# Can I evaluate two workbooks worksheets names, and if they have the same name then move on to the next sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I have two workbooks with POSSIBLY the same worksheets with the same names in them both.

[image: Workbook 1 example]

[image: Workbook 2 example]

My question is, can i evaluate all of the workbooks sheets names against the other, and if there are some missing from the first workbook then copy those over?

my code I have for copying them all over is this:

```
    Set wbk4 = Workbooks.Open("G:\Financial\Facility Work Papers and 
 Financials\8. Wage Reconcilliations\Wage Reconciliation 2017\December 2017 
completed\" & rngFacility & " " & WageRec & " " & TwelveThirtyOne & ".xls")

For Each sh In wbk4.Worksheets
sh.Copy after:=wbk1.Sheets(wbk1.Sheets.Count)
Next sh
```

In this case my base workbook would be wbk4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing arguments to `CopyWorksheets` you can now have it copy them if the `Name`, as shown on the tab, doesn't exist. It avoids a double `For ... Loop` by using OERN (`On Error Resume Next`) to continue when `Set foundSheet = copySheetTo.Worksheets(ws.Name)` would raise an error. If it would raise an error then `foundSheet` is `Nothing` and copies it over accordingly. The loop sets `foundSheet` back to nothing in preparation for the next check.

```
Sub Testing()
    Dim wbk4 As Workbook
    Set wbk4 = Workbooks.Open("G:\Financial\Facility Work Papers and Financials\8. Wage Reconcilliations\Wage Reconciliation 2017\December 2017 completed\" & rngFacility & " " & WageRec & " " & TwelveThirtyOne & ".xls")

    Dim newBook As Workbook
    Set newBook = Workbooks.Add
    CopyWorksheets wbk4, newBook
End Sub

Public Sub CopyWorksheets(ByVal sourceBook As Workbook, ByVal copySheetTo As Workbook)
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In sourceBook.Worksheets
        Dim foundSheet As Worksheet
        Set foundSheet = copySheetTo.Worksheets(ws.Name)

        If foundSheet Is Nothing Then
            ws.Copy After:=copySheetTo.Worksheets(copySheetTo.Worksheets.Count)
        End If
        Set foundSheet = Nothing
    Next
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the help ! Going to tweak it a bit for my current code, but this is will work.